# Install eclipse p2 sites automatically?

Tags: eclipse, p2

My requirement is

```
1. Take a bare eclipse installation (runtime platform)
2. Install a p2 update site-A
3. Install a p2 update site-B
4. Install a p2 update site-C
5. Run some basic test on this eclipse application.
```

Installing p2 update site is a nightmare! It takes lot of time and fails very frequently with validations.

Is there any automated way using which we can install all p2 sites automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Eclipse p2 director](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_director.html) for headless installations or de-installations. If you have an existing eclipse installation (done via p2), you can use it to install or de-install IUs.

Make sure to use proper profile name e.g. SDKprofile for eclipse IDE.
Another hurdle is to amend ".feature.group" to the feature ID , if you install a feature.

```
<eclipseSDK>\eclipsec.exe
   -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
   -repository <update-site-A>
   -tag addingSiteA
   -destination <bare-eclipse-installation>
   -profile SDKProfile
   -installIU <container.IU.feature.group>
```

Same thing for the other sites. If you have no  give a comma separated list of IUs you want to install.